# Connecting Quickbooks OAuth through Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to connect Quickbooks API through OAuth. I've added the OAuth 2 library to the Apps Script and deployed the Web App. The Web App URL is what I'm using as an URI in the OAuthService call and I've also set it up in the Quickbooks URI parameters. I get the Quickbooks site to open to authorize, but then I keep getting errors from Google or Intuit.

Code looks like this:

```
function getAuthorizationUrl() {
  console.log('getAuthorizationUrl called');
  var service = getOAuthService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    return authorizationUrl;
  }
}

function getOAuthService() {
  var REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/[SCRIPT_ID]/usercallback/';
  return OAuth2.createService('QuickBooks')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2')
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer')
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
      .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope('com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting')
      .setTokenHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      });
}
```

I'm currently getting this error even though the URIs are the same in both ends.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adOVr.png)

> The redirect_uri query parameter value is invalid. Make sure it is
> listed in the Redirect URIs section on your app's keys tab and matches
> it exactly. Click here to learn more about the redirect_uri query
> parameter.

Any suggestion? I've tried all possible configurations for the URI.

EDIT:

**Solution**: Use `OAuth2.getRedirectUri()`

Comment: The message is pretty clear, so you may want to double-check your redirect URI. The OAuth2 library doesn't require setting the redirect URI as it's provided automatically, so you may want to remove that set call and use the value provided by `service.getRedirectUri()`.

Comment: @Diego Believe me I had tripled checked and the URIs where the same. What worked now is using `OAuth2.getRedirectUri()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Use `OAuth2.getRedirectUri()`

Comment: Please explain how and why for future readers to understand